# What would be the healthiest way to gain weight?

Tags: nutrition

I'm 15 6' 2" 150 pounds and I'm looking to put myself at atleast 165-170. I lift weights for baseball and although I look very fit I'm not as strong as I would like to be. I am very fast for my age and I'm looking to play football. I've been lifting weights on and off with the baseball team for 2 years and haven't seen major improvements in strength, I think my late puberty might have also played a role. I try my hardest and am very motivated in the weight room but I can never gain anything. I always hear my friends say it's because I don't have any fat to build on but I diet strictly on twice my body weight in carbs at least a day and as much protein as I can find ( over 130 a day ). I've tried protein shakes as directed as they've been recommended to me by my coaches. I even tryed the heavyweight gainer 900 by champion performance as a last ditch effort to gain something. I've gained 5 pounds in probably a year. I don't avoid sugars and have never tracked my calories before but I always figured it would be pretty high. I've been dieting like this for almost a year 3 meals a day and a bedtime snack and a granola bar here and there in class. I've been fairly light my whole life. My mom also has trouble gaining weight like me. To get to the point, what would be the best way for someone like me to gain weight? And no it's not a tapeworm. I've asked my doctors about my dilemma and they've just told me its my metabolism and eventually it will slow down. I figured there's something I can do to gain weight. I just need some advice.

Comment: Please consider accepting @JJosaur's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The technically healthiest way to gain weight is to take a 'balanced' diet and then increase the portion size to result in a calorie surplus.

A common way for young people to gain weight and be successful in progressing in strength is to pair GOMAD with a compound barbell routine like Starting Strength.

[GOMAD](https://stronglifts.com/gomad-milk-squats-gallon-gain-weight/) stands for Gallon Of Milk A Day. The principle is simple: whole milk, every day, 1 gallon, pair with compound exercise and your standard diet.

Comment: From what I know it was demonstrated that milk is not that healthy ,only if you get it from farms.If you buy them from stores the pasteurized milk was demonstrated to be harmful to bones.Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that claim has no basis in reality: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/150/does-drinking-milk-lead-to-osteoporosis

Comment: I would like to ask you, in case of  GOMAD, is it possible to drink say milk instead of the whole milk ? What is your thinking about that .

Comment: Don’t waste your time with low fat, skimmed or half-skimmed milk. They’re lower in saturated fats & calories and won’t give the same results. Go with whole milk, it also tastes better. Whole Milk. Full fat milk which contains 3-4% fat. Alternative names: full cream milk or homo milk. 3-4% fat. Check the nutrient data on the whole milk you buy. It should contain 3-4g fat, 3g protein & 5g carbs per 100ml. 2400 Calories. Whole milk contains 60kcals per 100ml. This accounts for 2400kcals when you drink 1 gallon whole milk.